# Change Tables values based on DROPDOWN

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, html-table, html-select

Based on Value Selected in Drop-down data in table below is changed?

Sample Code is mentioned below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="FirstSet">Set1
  <option value="SecondSet">Set2
  <option value="ThirdSet">Set3
  <option value="FourthSet">Set4
</select>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    if (x == 'FirstSet' ) {
    x = 99;
    } else { x = 88; } 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
</script>

<table>
 <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><a >AA <button type="button" style="float: right;" >1</button></a></td>
        <td><a >BB <button type="button" style="float: right;" >3</button></a></td>
        <td><a >CC <button type="button" style="float: right;" >2</button></a></td>
        <td><a >DD <button type="button" style="float: right;" >4</button></a></td>      
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a >AAA <button type="button" style="float: right;" >5</button></a></td>
        <td><a >BBB <button type="button" style="float: right;" >6</button></a></td>
        <td><a >CCC <button type="button" style="float: right;" >9</button></a></td>
        <td><a >DDD <button type="button" style="float: right;" >8</button></a></td>     
      </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Set 1 is default values in tables;

Set 1 (Default)
AA = 1; BB = 3 ; CC = 2 ; DD = 4
AAA = 5; BBB = 6 ; CCC = 9 ; DDD = 8

If I select Set2 values mentioned below must get replaced with new values as mentioned below

Set 2
AA = 11; BB = 33 ; CC = 44 ; DD = 88
AAA = 15; BBB = 45 ; CCC = 67 ; DDD = 8

In Same way there are different values for each set.

Instead of changing value at each

level; how can I change all values together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **[map](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)** function .And use query selector.It will select  `a>button` .Assign your all values into array and match with them.

```
var a_tag=document.querySelectorAll('a > button');
            rep_array.map(function(a,b){
            a_tag[b].innerHTML=a;
              })
```

```js
var rep_array=[11, 33 ,44 ,88,15,45 ,67 ,8]
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    if (x == 'FirstSet' ) {
    x = 99;
    } else { x = 88;
            var a_tag=document.querySelectorAll('a > button');
            rep_array.map(function(a,b){
            a_tag[b].innerHTML=a;
              })
           } 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
```

```html
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="FirstSet">Set1
  <option value="SecondSet">Set2
  <option value="ThirdSet">Set3
  <option value="FourthSet">Set4
</select>

<p id="demo"></p>

<table>
 <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><a >AA <button type="button" style="float: right;" >1</button></a></td>
        <td><a >BB <button type="button" style="float: right;" >3</button></a></td>
        <td><a >CC <button type="button" style="float: right;" >2</button></a></td>
        <td><a >DD <button type="button" style="float: right;" >4</button></a></td>      
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a >AAA <button type="button" style="float: right;" >5</button></a></td>
        <td><a >BBB <button type="button" style="float: right;" >6</button></a></td>
        <td><a >CCC <button type="button" style="float: right;" >9</button></a></td>
        <td><a >DDD <button type="button" style="float: right;" >8</button></a></td>     
      </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Another one is [**forEach()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp) Match with index of both array and element

```
 a_tag.forEach(function(a,b){
           a_tag[b].innerHTML=rep_array[b];
           })
```

```js
var rep_array=[11, 33 ,44 ,88,15,45 ,67 ,8]
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    if (x == 'FirstSet' ) {
    x = 99;
    } else { x = 88;
            var a_tag=document.querySelectorAll('a > button');
            a_tag.forEach(function(a,b){
               a_tag[b].innerHTML=rep_array[b];
               })
              
           } 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
```

```html
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="FirstSet">Set1
  <option value="SecondSet">Set2
  <option value="ThirdSet">Set3
  <option value="FourthSet">Set4
</select>

<p id="demo"></p>

<table>
 <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><a >AA <button type="button" style="float: right;" >1</button></a></td>
        <td><a >BB <button type="button" style="float: right;" >3</button></a></td>
        <td><a >CC <button type="button" style="float: right;" >2</button></a></td>
        <td><a >DD <button type="button" style="float: right;" >4</button></a></td>      
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a >AAA <button type="button" style="float: right;" >5</button></a></td>
        <td><a >BBB <button type="button" style="float: right;" >6</button></a></td>
        <td><a >CCC <button type="button" style="float: right;" >9</button></a></td>
        <td><a >DDD <button type="button" style="float: right;" >8</button></a></td>     
      </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store your different sets in one JSON file and call them based on selected set. 
like {"set1" :[{"AA":"1","BB":"1" ...}]}. To get values from JSON file , use  XMLHTTPRequest or $.getJSON (JQuery)